# how to redirect page in ajax with the data you send to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i want to redirect another page after success,
the code is working fine but i cannot get the data i have passed

this is my jquery

```
     $.ajax({
         type:'GET',
         url:link,
         data:data,
         success:function(response){
             alert(response);
             if(response === 'true'){
                 $('.message').html('No table found for the specified number of guests.');
             }
             else if(response === 'false'){
                 $('.message').html('The Restaurant is full on this date and time.');
             }
             else{
                  window.location.href = link;
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

this is my controller

```
public function myReservation(){


        $location= $this->input->get('location');
        $guest= $this->input->get('guest');
        $date= $this->input->get('date');
        $time= $this->input->get('time');
        $result =$this->reservation_model->getTables($guest);
        $query = $this->reservation_model->getReservations($location,$guest,$date,$time);
        if($result){
            echo 'true';
        }
        else if($query){
            echo 'false';
        }else{
        $queryy['getData'] = $this->input->get();
        $this->load->view('my_reservation',$queryy);
        }
    }
```

there are no errors displaying just going to redirect page without get data

Comment: i don't get what you are trying to accomplish here. you have a ajax response that can either output `true` `false` or a view? that is odd. especially considering given a view is outputted, according to your ajax that means that it is directly assigned to a js redirect? weird. on top of that "cannot get the data I passed", what does that mean?

Comment: i need to check both the database functions getTables,getReservations, so i have taken if else if

Comment: i think you misunderstand how ajax works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you are trying to do with your else block in `myReservation()` function. You are calling a function through `ajax` and if the result is neither `true` or `false` then you want to redirect to that function with the values you passed, there is a way. Here you are passing the data in ajax options. Instead of that you can modify your link as follows:

```
var link = 'myReservation?location=location_value&guest=guest_value&date=date_value&time=time_value'
```

Then remove the `data` option from ajax.
This way when the response is neither true or false, then you will be able to redirect to `myReservation` with the values.

Comment: i need to check both the database functions getTables,getReservations, so i have taken if else if

Comment: viewing my_reservation page

Comment: yeah it worked but can i use only if else once in my function and ajax?

Comment: $result and $query are false then it goes to else part view